# IntelliJ IDEA JSX code style

Tags: intellij-idea, coding-style, reactjs

I have a JSX file with two-space indents, but IntelliJ keeps adding four-space indents. Changing `Settings>Editor>Code Style` for Javascript, HTML, and "other file types" does not seem to affect this.

How can I change the code style for JSX files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the reason the IDE wasn't responding to my settings changes is it was using EditorConfig mode (`Settings>Editor>Code Style>EditorConfig`). Editing the `.editorconfig` file to have the line `indent_size = 2` fixed the issue.